# how to copy a word without put the cursor in front of it in vim

Tags: vim

As I know ,to copy a word in vim, use the command 'byw',
Is there a shorter way to do that? Only use 'y' and another character so that I don't have to move the cursor in front of the word?
To delete a word is so much like above,any ideas?
Thanks for help

Answer (score 3):

`yiw` is yank in word, `diw` delete in word, `ciw` change in word (deletes and puts you in insert mode)

Maybe that helps?

Comment: More Info - on the above : 
"diw" - Gives deleting the word without the spaces. but "daw" gives deleting the word with space. Example if I have "word1 word2 word3" and your cursor in word2, diw results in "word1  word3" where as daw results in "word1 word3" - See the difference in space. similarly "dw" deletes till end of the word from the current position.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>y</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>  (depending on where in/after the word the cursor is currently)

In general, you can combine any motion command after the <kbd>y</kbd>.  The <kbd>b</kbd> motion moves to the beginning of the word.  <kbd>w</kbd> moves to the beginning of the next word.  So <kbd>b</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> and <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> are the same, if your cursor is currently at the beginning of the next word.  <kbd>b</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> is similar to <kbd>b</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> except it yanks only until the end of the current word (so excludes whitespace between it and the next word).

Simply replace the <kbd>y</kbd> in each of the above with <kbd>d</kbd> for delete.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an operator-pending map for the `daw` and `diw` commands to use only two keys. For example:

```
onoremap I iw
onoremap A aw
```

Now you can use `dI` and it will act like `diw` and `dA` will act like `daw`.